# Return value in getter method if object not found

Tags: java, exception

I am wondering what is the best design for this problem. I have a `Season` object which which has an `ArrayList<Episode>` which contains every episode in a season for a given TV show. Now let's say I want to search for episode 25 of a given season for a given TV show. Is the following design appropriate (throwing an Exception) or would it be better to create an object in a state of error, return that and let the calling method figure what's wrong ?

```
public class Season {
    public Episode GetEpisode(int ep_no) throws Exception {
        for(Episode ep : episodes)
            if(ep.GetEpisodeNumber() == ep_no) return ep;
        throw(new Exception("Episode not found."));
    }

    private ArrayList<Episode> episodes;
}
```

Comment: you should have a dictionary.. and throw your own Exception instead of generic exception

Comment: what about just returning null

Comment: Why are you iterating over the `episodes` to check if `ep_no` exists, and not checking the size of `episodes`?

Comment: @vidit It is not impossible that an episode might be missing. Even if it does not occur very often I want to account for this possibility.

Comment: @aaronman: I guess I'm too new to Java to have figured this one on my own !

Comment: @nachokk This may be a bit off-topic but I'd like to know why a Dictionary would be better in this case ? I'm still pretty much learning Java.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur searchs in dictionary are faster than list, but i didn't realize that season is for a program show, may u have to use `SET`, or a dictionary with (nroProgram,program) , your arrayList could be a dictionary if all programs are consecutive xD, imagine that you are looping for searching an episode, if has 10 million

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur - Sounds good, I was just asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends.  First of all, I wouldn't throw a bare `Exception`.  I'd create a new type of exception.  Perhaps an `EpisodeNotFoundException`.  That way it's more descriptive.

Second, does the code need to handle this situation when it occurs, or is it something that *shouldn't* fail.  If it would require programmer intervention, you should throw an exception that extends `RuntimeException` instead.  Code that throws `RuntimeException` does not need to be handled by the code that calls it.

Also, is it an *error* if an episode isn't found, or is it a completely acceptable thing to occur?  If it's acceptable, you should probably return `null` instead.  This is the way `Map.get()` works.

Comment: It's completely acceptable. It really should be an "exception" rather than a recurring thing but I want to account for this.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur I'm getting mixed messages from that reply.  If it's acceptable but you want to account for it, then just have the code that calls `GetEpisode` check `if (response == null) {...}`

Comment: I'm sorry if my reply wasn't quite clear. I just want to be able to know if the episode is found or not. If it's not then it's very fine but the calling method should know that it was not found. Checking for `null` would be perfect indeed ! I will allow checkmark when it's available.